# What is application of following exercise?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, compactness, applications

I had done following excercise.

> Consider the function $f:X\to Y$ where Y is compact Hausdorff space. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if the graph of $f$,
>   $$G_f=\{(x,f(x)) \mid x\in X\},$$
>   is closed

I had done this exercise.

I wanted to know what is application of this exercise? From the question itself, I get that if the graph is closed with the given property then I can conclude that function is continuous. Is there any other application which can be done directly using this?

I know this is a soft question, but I am interested. I am thankful if someone helps me.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: May I know why some one down voted ?

Comment: I've wondered about the same question for some time. Since this is labelled as 'theorem' by Munkres, which is a bit unusual...

Comment: @YuiToCheng Yes Same to you...

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha:G_1\to G_2$ is a continuous homorophism between two topological groups where $G_2$ is compact. Then $H:=G_1\times \alpha(G_1)$ is a closed subgroup of $G:=G_1\times G_2$ and the quotient $G/H$ is Hausdorff. i.e, a topological group!

Comment: @AmratA You mean $H=Gr(\alpha)$. Cause $G_1\times\alpha(G_1)$ does not have to be closed in $G_1\times G_2$ since $\alpha(G_1)$ need not be closed in $G_2$. Also the quotient is always a topological group (regardless of continuity of $\alpha$) as long as the graph is normal in $G_1\times G_2$ (which again doesn't have to). So the only thing we obtain is that $(G_1\times G_2)/H$ is Hausdorff which is somewhat interesting I guess? But is it really useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a fun fact and has no serious application that I know of, at least.

It's classical that graphs of continuous functions to Hausdorff spaces are always closed and the fun fact is that compactness of $Y$ (Hausdorff not needed for that direction) is enough to go back. It shows the power of compactness in a way.

The graph of $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; f(x)=\frac{1}{x} (x \neq 0), f(0)=0$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but that function is not continuous, so we do need some condition: just a closed graph is not enough.

There is also is a nice parallel to the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem) for linear functions between Banach spaces (which does have a lot of applications but is unrelated to the general topology fact under discussion).